# Castle Windsor throws a CommunicationObjectFaultedException when disposing a WCF client that has thrown a MessageSecurityException

Tags: c#, wcf, castle-windsor

I have an ASP.NET MVC application with a controller that uses a WCF service. The web application is authenticated by the WCF service using WIF and a Security Token Service (STS). This requires that the WCF service has the STS cert thumbprint in its web.config (<system.identityModel>). When a WCF service method is called and the WCF service is configured with a wrong thumbprint the service method throws an exception:

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party. See the inner FaultException for the fault code and detail. ---> System.ServiceModel.FaultException: An error occurred when processing the security tokens in the message.     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---     at 
System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)     at 
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.End(SendAsyncResult result)     at 
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)     at 
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.TaskCreator.<>c__DisplayClass5`1.<CreateGenericTask>b__4(IAsyncResult asyncResult)     at 
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---     at 
System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)     at 
Helper.GetMessages(String func) in xxx  ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party. See the inner FaultException for the fault code and detail. ---> System.ServiceModel.FaultException: An error occurred when processing the security tokens in the message.     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---     at 
System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)     at 
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.End(SendAsyncResult result)     at 
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)     at 
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.TaskCreator.<>c__DisplayClass5`1.<CreateGenericTask>b__4(IAsyncResult asyncResult)     at 
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)<---
```

In the MVC controller we catch any exceptions thrown by the service since we want to return a response even if there is a problem with the service:

```
try {
    service.Hello();
}
catch (Exception e) {
    log.Error("Service error", e);
}
```

The controller method returns the ViewResult and Castle Windsor starts cleaning up the controller and its dependencies. However when Windsor disposes the WCF client that threw the MessageSecurityException I get this exception:

```
[CommunicationObjectFaultedException: The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state.]
System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) +14579646
System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type) +622
System.IDisposable.Dispose() +0
Castle.MicroKernel.LifecycleConcerns.DisposalConcern.Apply(ComponentModel model, Object component) in c:\Downloads\Windsor-3.3\Windsor-3.3\src\Castle.Windsor\MicroKernel\LifecycleConcerns\DisposalConcern.cs:47
Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.AbstractComponentActivator.ApplyConcerns(IEnumerable`1 steps, Object instance) in c:\Downloads\Windsor-3.3\Windsor-3.3\src\Castle.Windsor\MicroKernel\ComponentActivator\AbstractComponentActivator.cs:120
Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.AbstractComponentActivator.ApplyDecommissionConcerns(Object instance) in c:\Downloads\Windsor-3.3\Windsor-3.3\src\Castle.Windsor\MicroKernel\ComponentActivator\AbstractComponentActivator.cs:132
Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration.WcfClientActivator.ApplyDecommissionConcerns(Object instance) in c:\Downloads\Windsor-3.3\Windsor-3.3\src\Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration\Client\WcfClientActivator.cs:64
Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.InternalDestroy(Object instance) in c:\Downloads\Windsor-3.3\Windsor-3.3\src\Castle.Windsor\MicroKernel\ComponentActivator\DefaultComponentActivator.cs:74
Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.AbstractComponentActivator.Destroy(Object instance) in c:\Downloads\Windsor-3.3\Windsor-3.3\src\Castle.Windsor\MicroKernel\ComponentActivator\AbstractComponentActivator.cs:87
Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.AbstractLifestyleManager.Release(Object instance) in c:\Downloads\Windsor-3.3\Windsor-3.3\src\Castle.Windsor\MicroKernel\Lifestyle\AbstractLifestyleManager.cs:64
Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.DefaultHandler.ReleaseCore(Burden burden) in c:\Downloads\Windsor-3.3\Windsor-3.3\src\Castle.Windsor\MicroKernel\Handlers\DefaultHandler.cs:65
Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.AbstractHandler.Release(Burden burden) in c:\Downloads\Windsor-3.3\Windsor-3.3\src\Castle.Windsor\MicroKernel\Handlers\AbstractHandler.cs:170
Castle.MicroKernel.Burden.Release() in c:\Downloads\Windsor-3.3\Windsor-3.3\src\Castle.Windsor\MicroKernel\Burden.cs:119
Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.Scoped.ScopeCache.<Dispose>b__0(Burden b) in c:\Downloads\Windsor-3.3\Windsor-3.3\src\Castle.Windsor\MicroKernel\Lifestyle\Scoped\ScopeCache.cs:65
Castle.Core.Internal.CollectionExtensions.ForEach(IEnumerable`1 items, Action`1 action) in d:\work\16de7b8c88ab14af\src\Castle.Core\Core\Internal\CollectionExtensions.cs:44
Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.Scoped.ScopeCache.Dispose() in c:\Downloads\Windsor-3.3\Windsor-3.3\src\Castle.Windsor\MicroKernel\Lifestyle\Scoped\ScopeCache.cs:65
Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.Scoped.DefaultLifetimeScope.Dispose() in c:\Downloads\Windsor-3.3\Windsor-3.3\src\Castle.Windsor\MicroKernel\Lifestyle\Scoped\DefaultLifetimeScope.cs:38
Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.PerWebRequestLifestyleModule.Application_EndRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Downloads\Windsor-3.3\Windsor-3.3\src\Castle.Windsor\MicroKernel\Lifestyle\PerWebRequestLifestyleModule.cs:47
System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +92
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +165
```

The code that throws the exception is:

```
AbstractComponentActivator.ApplyConcerns(IEnumerable<IDecommissionConcern> steps, object instance)
DisposalConcern.Apply(ComponentModel model, object component)
```

When debugging I have noticed the following difference:

When service.Hello(); is called and the frameowrk throws a MessageSecurityException
then `object component =  {System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy}`
in  `DisposalConcern.Apply(ComponentModel model, object component)`
this throws the CommunicationObjectFaultedException

When service.Hello(); is called and I throw new Exception("test")
then `object component = {System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.__TransparentProxy}`
in  `DisposalConcern.Apply(ComponentModel model, object component)` 
this does not throw an exception

The service is registered as follows in the web application:

```
public class MeldingssystemServiceInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(Component.For<IMeldingssystemService>()
            .AsWcfClient(new DefaultClientModel(WcfEndpoint.FromConfiguration("MeldingssystemService")))
        .LifeStyle.PerWebRequest);
    }
}
```

I’m trying to figure out if this is a bug/limitation in Castle Windsor or a configuration error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause of the error was a regression bug in the castle windsor wcf facility. The bug has been fixed in version 4.1.0 of the nuget package Castle.WcfIntegrationFacility.

The order of the cleanup statements has been changed, for details see https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/issues/104

Answer (score 1):

You could add abort statement on the OnDestroy event:

```
public class MeldingssystemServiceInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(Component.For<IMeldingssystemService>()
            .AsWcfClient(new DefaultClientModel(WcfEndpoint.FromConfiguration("MeldingssystemService")))
            .LifeStyle.PerWebRequest.OnDestroy(service =>
            {
                var channel = (IClientChannel) service;

                if (channel.State == CommunicationState.Faulted)
                    channel.Abort();
            }));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding an abort statement:

```
try {
    service.Hello();
}
catch (Exception e) {
    service.abort();    
    log.Error("Service error", e);   
}
```

See the following : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/74129/The-Proper-Use-and-Disposal-of-WCF-Channels-or-Com

Good luck,

Marwijn.

Comment: Hi, I’am aware of the Indisposable WCF client problem. Castle Windsor already handles faulted clients (`Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration.Internal.WcfUtils`). If the service throws an exception it will be in the faulted state and Windsor is able to dispose of the client properly. The problem is if the service has thrown a MessageSecurityException Windsor is not able to dispose of the client properly.
I could add `((IClientChannel)service).Abort();` in the catch block, but it seems a bit hacky. I want Castle Windsor to handle the lifestyle of the objects.